# Django multiple delete does not work

Tags: django, django-admin

I have the following delete method, this works when deleting just 1 record individually but not when deleting multiple ones in the admin i.e. via list view, why and how to fix?

```
def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):

        this = Profile.objects.get(id=self.id)
        this.image.delete(save=True)

        super(Profile, self).delete(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend using `signals` to delete your related image, check out the `pre_delete signal` in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#pre-delete).

Comment: why signals vs a method or is that a can of worms?

Comment: Admin's delete calls a queryset's `delete` method, instead of going down to the individual models. As it says in the link @msc provided, that signal is triggered for deletes on both the individual model and querysets.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that this won't work with Django 1.3 or earlier. Just a heads up there.

Answer (score 1):

The Django docs actually mention your exact situation with the admin action: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/actions/

Alternatively, you could look into overriding the default Manager and QuerySet models, if you want to use `Model.objects.delete` elsewhere.

Comment: or you could use the `pre_delete` signal that @msc mentioned. I wasn't aware that signals were triggered for querysets, since it looks like that functionality was added in Django 1.4 and most of my experience has been with 1.3.